# My Google Chrome crashed after I've used it many times

Tags: google-chrome, browser

My Chrome crashes, I don't know what happened to it

```
This webpage is not available.

The webpage at https://gmail.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
More information on this error
Below is the original error message

Error 104 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED): The attempt to connect to the server failed.
```

I searched about this, the things that i Understood was that it is about Malwares or about cookies.
I cleared my cookies.
I ran Malwarebytes and clean and removed malwares and then I restarted my computer but again it crashed. I didn't find another solution

I uninstalled and installed it again too, but nothing changed.

Also I disabled my firewall but no changes
maybe it is about port 80 that is for this browser
well! I don't know what I have installed! that used port 80
after using my lovely chrome:"(

I have access to internet by another browsers like Firefox

Comment: Does your internet generally work?

Comment: yes I have fire fox and it works like a charm

Comment: http://mail.google.com is the proper address, I think they gave up `www.gmail.com`

Comment: I am in gmail always do you mean I must ask there? I saw the people asking in there n actually I tried the solutions too

Comment: I was just saying not to use that `gmail.com` address, I think it's gone rogue.  See [this](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=8253) around the middle of the page.

Comment: The gmail.com should still point to mail.google.com. Besides, I'm assuming that Negin can't access any other sites either.

Comment: Do you have a firewall or antivirus installed? Check to make sure it's not blocking Chrome.

Comment: ys I have checked them in exception I choose in system&services google chrome then it isn't blocked with firewall Also I tried it with disabled firewall too yes I have node32 I disabled it too n In ports in http I cleared port 80 that was in node32 too

Comment: yes Nono Your assuming is correct I can't access any site